# ASP .NET or Django?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm new to the web framework, but have been using Java/Servlet/JSP for my previous web development because I hate PHP. I'm thinking of starting a new feature laden website that I need to quickly create and been deciding on numerous technologies.

I dabbled in Drupal for a while and found it too restrictive and didn't particularly enjoy constantly trying to find a module that almost do what you want so I'm moving over to a web framework.

I considered ASP .NET or Django. Searching on this site, I found a couple of questions ("[Is there any advantage to Django versus ASP.NET MVC other than platform? [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697686/is-there-any-advantage-to-django-versus-asp-net-mvc-other-than-platform)" and ["ASP.NET MVC vs. Django - Which framework should I learn?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97006/asp-net-mvc-vs-django-which-framework-should-i-learn)), but they don't fit my situation.

In my case, I'm new to Python and have to learn that, but am relatively familiar with C# due to Java/C++/XNA and VB Classic 6.0. In both cases, I have no experience with Django/Python or ASP .NET/SQL Server and have never created a site with either.

My reasons are as follows:

- I like the idea of having a full stack from one vendor and not mock around with Linux as it took me forever to setup a proper secure setup of Ubuntu, PHP, MySQL and Apache. I don't want technical oddities of learning gazillion different applications with obscure settings to get it working. This is mostly a concern with Django/Python as I believe MS got their stuff well tied togheter.
- Django is designed for newspaper website so it focuses on rapid and efficient development of new features with good design principles. I love the idea of there is only one good way to do it and the Django authors perfectionism. The pitfall of course is since 2005 they are still on version 1.2! Ruby on Rails is far ahead of them considering I saw this [video](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2939556954580527226#). Yeah, I watched the whole entire 3-hours, but didn't understand much from the RoR demonstration.
- ASP .NET is appealing to me because I already know C# and VB Classic 6.0. I'm familiar with Visual Studio and like the fact that it is also tied in to Windows Phone 7/Xbox Live Indie games with XNA. However, if those features are used is another question down the road. However, as mentioned before ASP .NET just seemed streamelined with plenty of documentation and support. Future job prospects also seem more in favor with MS technology.

What does the community here think?

I would like to hear different ideas as I beginning web programmer it is very daunting and I have vasted far too much time figuring this out on my own the hard way. Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: 1) What does PHP have to do here? 2) Django is not sill on the same version! There have been lots of updates since 2005 (which was the *initial* release). 3) Apache and MySQL are hardly “obscure”

Comment: Why not consider the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org)? You would probably feel much more familiar with that, and it seems to have many of the benefits of a fast coding web MVC framework like Django... (btw, I **am** an ASP.NET MVC developer).

Comment: "The pitfall of course is since 2005 they are still on version 1.2!" The version number has zero relevance. Wine is version 1.2, yet has existed since 1993. That does not say anything about how often it is updated or how fast it is progressing - it's just a number.

Comment: @Liquid_Fire: You are correct, version number is arbitrary. Unfortunately for Django, they are slowly moving towards Python 3 support. With each increment in the 1.x they get closer and currently moving at a pace of an increment per 9 months. It seems this process will take at least 2-3 years from now.
@Agos: Django has added a lot of feature (as far as I can tell), but overall they are moving forward much slower than other competing projects. PHP comment is to indicate my disdain for that type of programming giving insight into my background. It isn't intended to insult anyone preference.

Comment: @rsennal: Play Framework is interresting, I will have to look more into it. Thanks!

Comment: -1: It is a bad question, too argumentative and inflammatory (lots of biased opinions).

Comment: I agree that the question is too argumentative. The OP seems to have already made up his mind. he alredy dislikes PHP, does not thin much of Python and its tie in with Linux and Apache, and is already sold to ASP.NET. Why ask this question then?

Comment: @MAK: I'm actually not sold on to ASP .NET, in fact I'm leaning towards Django, but concerned about the long term prospect of a product that seems to move forward slowly and then there is always the issue of Python 3.0 support. My experience with Java and I "assume" ASP .NET is the same is that it is very verbose. I want efficient and rapid development. It is a very opinionated question  based on my concerns. I would appreciate some focus on the question as opposed to criticizing it.

Comment: If you hate PHP, and you have a choice, then don't chose it

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net and WISC# stack.

WISC - Windows/IIS/SqlServer/C# :)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote :) For a person familiar with Java I think it is easier and quicker to build using C#/ASP.net. Nothing against Django, I'd prefer Django over other frameworks though :) but it requires some learning and the user asking this question asked for something quick.

Comment: @Sandeep Singh Rawat: Do you think long term, I would be better off just learning Python/Django? I'm imagining it will take a full month to learning Python and Django. I kind of dislike the Java way and C# is practically that with some C++ sprinkling in it.

Comment: IMO, In long term you should learn both. Personally I'm inclined towards C#/ASP.net as it is more productive and you can take leverage of Visual Studio (most powerful IDE). You can try both Django and some open source .net cms and decide for yourself which one do you prefer.

Comment: @Sandeep Singh Rawat: Why do you think C#/ASP .Net is more productive? Everything I have read seems to indicate the old Java way is outdated. Are there any tools in there that makes it more efficient? I do agree Visual Studio is very nice. Unfortunately, time is of essence and learning yet another language in the timeframe I have is not really an option.

Comment: Go for the one you are comfortable with. look at the libraries available and your hosting requirements and choose the one that suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an MVC Web Framework use ASP.net MVC , since you come from a Java Background C# wont be a problem for you

Django is a good framework but you have to learn python